# Xen Server 6.2 won't start after hotfix install

Tags: xen, xenserver

I've installed latest Xen Server 6.2 hotfix [SP1053](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX219201)

**My bad, I don't check enough and missing some previous patches.** Now server boots and is accessible via ssh but XAPI won't start. *xe-toolstack-restart* didn't help. Has only plenty of errors

Looks like service command is missing.

```
/opt/xensource/bin/xe-toolstack-restart: line 24: service: command not found
/opt/xensource/bin/xe-toolstack-restart: line 25: service: command not found
/opt/xensource/bin/xe-toolstack-restart: line 26: service: command not found
/opt/xensource/bin/xe-toolstack-restart: line 27: service: command not found
/opt/xensource/bin/xe-toolstack-restart: line 28: service: command not found
/opt/xensource/bin/xe-toolstack-restart: line 29: service: command not found
/opt/xensource/bin/xe-toolstack-restart: line 30: service: command not found
/opt/xensource/bin/xe-toolstack-restart: line 31: service: command not found
/opt/xensource/bin/xe-toolstack-restart: line 32: service: command not found
/opt/xensource/bin/xe-toolstack-restart: line 33: service: command not found
```

I'm thinking to install missing patches, but don't know how to do it without XAPI.

Answer (score 1):

> ...
>   /opt/xensource/bin/xe-toolstack-restart: line 33: **service: command not found**

This is telling you that the `service` command cannot be found by the script. You just need to add `/sbin` to you path so

```
export PATH=/sbin:$PATH
xe-toolstack-restart
```

should do the trick

<sub>Yeah, I've been caught out by that too</sub>